# Get text of a modified stylesheet (Firefox)

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am programmatically (JS) rewriting stylesheets for a web page. (I have a copy of the page and all assets stored locally on a server.)  Once I'm done rewriting the stylesheets, I would like to save the modified versions out to disk.

I am using Webdriver to run my own JS on the page while it is loaded in Firefox.

In IE, [it appears](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/externalcss2.shtml#.UjuZ1mSZ1Kg) that you can access a `stylesheet.cssText` property to get the stylesheet source stored into a JS string, which would be sufficient.  However, I don't have the option of using IE, so I would like to figure out a way to accomplish the same end in Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use something like the following ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LS8Cx/)):

```
for (var si = 0; si < document.styleSheets.length; ++si) {
    var ss = document.styleSheets[si];

    var href = ss.href || "<inline>";
    var rules = [];
    for (var ri = 0; ri < ss.cssRules.length; ++ri) {
        rules.push(ss.cssRules[ri].cssText);
    }
}
```

Read the MDN docs, in particular ["Using dynamic styling information"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_dynamic_styling_information).

Comment: Right now, I'm doing this and concatenating the rules' cssText together to form one big string that I save to disk as the CSS file.  Do you know if this ends up losing any information from the original CSS file?  It seems to be working fine so far.

Comment: Shouldn't be losing information. But may transform some stuff or add additional stuff: see e.g. `html background` in my fiddle ;) IIRC the web developer tools (and some other code) use this API as well.