# Retrieving the actual DOM/css state of a web page through javascript

Tags: javascript, css, dom, firefox-addon

As you know, a web page is the union of a html file, one or more css files and one or more javascript files: the first two elements are parsed by the browser to generate the DOM and other data structures useful for the rendering of the page .

Javascript files are executed by an engine, and they can change the value of the DOM or of the data structures related to css, so that, after the execution of a javascript, the "actual status" of a web page can be different from what was statically described by the original html and css code.

I need to develop a firefox add-on that grabs the "actual status" of a web page and stores it to disk, as a couple html + css file.

For the html file is quite easy, i need to serialize the DOM. My concerns are about the css: I can traverse the DOM and for each element get its stylesheet, but it will be 
extremely slow and produces a not optimized css code.

Let's make an example

I have this html code:

```
<html>
    <head>
         <title>Test</title>
         <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"  />
         <script type='text/javascript' src="changebackground.js" > </script>
    </head> 
    <body>
         <div  class="divclass" > 
            <form> 
                <h2>click to change the background</h2>
                <input type="button" value="version" onclick="changebg()" />
            </form>
         </div>
    </body>
```

Style.css has this definitions:

```
.divclass{
          margin: .5in; 
          height: 400px;
}

body{
      background-color: white;
      color: blueviolet;
}
```

and changebackground has this code:

```
function changebg() {
     document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'black';
 }
```

Obviously, after clicking the button the background's color becomes black.
My goal is to write an add-on that , after this change, gives me back the css with the style's modification, i.e.:

```
.divclass{
          margin: .5in; 
          height: 400px;
}

body{
      background-color: black;
      color: blueviolet;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to traverse anything. Inline styles are already part of the, so you get that for free, e.g.:

```
elem.style.width = "100px";
elem.outerHTML == '<elem style="width: 100px;>";
```

So to produce a "dump" of the current DOM, incl. inline styles, etc. do:

```
var html = document.documentElement.outerHTML;
```

You may also want to serialize [`document.doctype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.doctype).

In the unlikely event that a script actually messes with external stylesheets (`<link rel="stylesheet">`, you may do something like what I described in ["Get text of a modified stylesheet"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18907796/484441) to get the current set of rules. Again, inline styles (`<style>` and `style=` attributes) are already present in `.outerHTML`.

**EDIT**: What you ask now is not possible, because this is not how inline styles work.
Consider the following html fragment:

```
<div>first div</div>
<div>second div</div>
```

Now the following code runs:

```
document.querySelector("div").style.background = "black";
```

This will cause the first div to have an inline style:

```
<div style="background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% black;">first div</div>
<div>second div</div>
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QSSFX/)

How would that rule look like? `div { background: black; }` is obviously wrong, as this would affect all divs.

You could generate new classes and/or ids, but then you need to manipulate and store the DOM, and could have used my original answer in the first place.

Comment: I'm afraid you  missed the point. Your solution gives me back the original css values, but it seems to miss the changes made throught javascript. I updated the question with an example.

Comment: I didn't miss the point... You essentially changed your question.

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect your changes.

Comment: But Firebug seems to do something similar to my intentions, isn't it?

Comment: No, Firebug isn't. If you mean the Firebug style editor, then reread the part of my question discussing external CSS, because that is what the style editor (mostly) does: messing with the external rules.